# How to display a title from an array of objects?

Tags: arrays, angular, title

I'd like to display a title from an array of objects.

**Example 1:**

```html
<td [title]="car.passengers?.name">
    <strong>{{ car }}</strong>
</td>
```

This will display the title as `undefined`

**Example 2:**

```html
<td [title]="car.passengers[0]?.name">
    <strong>{{ car }}</strong>
</td>
```

This will display the first passenger only.

How do I get all the passengers?

Thanks.

Comment: use *ngFor to loop through all passengers

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngFor to loop

```
<td *ngFor="let passenger of car.passengers" [title]="passenger?.name">
    <strong>{{ car }}</strong>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NgFor in the td tag-

```
<td *ngFor="let passenger of car.passengers" [title]="passenger.name">
    <strong>{{ car }}</strong>
</td>
```